# Suppose $X$ has a topology induced by a map $f: X \to Y$. Show that $f_1 : X \to f[X]$, defines an open map.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Suppose $X$ has a topology induced by a map $f: X \to Y$. Show that $f_1 : X \to f[X]$, defines an open map.

By the induced topology I have that $\tau_X = \{ O \subset Y \mid f^{-1}[O] \in \tau_X\}$?

So take $U$ open in $X$, this means that $U = f^{-1}[O]$ for some $O \subset Y$.

Now I want to show that $f_1[U]$ is open in $f[X]$. So $$f_1[U] = f[U] = f[f^{-1}[O]] \cap f[X] = O \cap f[X]$$ which would be open since $O$ is open in $Y$? I’m not sure I understand the third equality e.g $f[f^{-1}[O]] \cap f[X] $ isn’t this due to the restriction of $f$ to $f[X]$ and valid since that?

Comment: Your definition of the induced topology doesn’t make sense. $\tau_X$ is used on both sides of the equation. Can you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Your induced topology is not quite ok. You are on the right track, but it should be

$$\tau_X=\{U\subseteq X\ |\ U=f^{-1}(O)\text{ for some open }O\subseteq Y\}$$

or in a short form

$$\tau_X=\{f^{-1}(O)\ |\ O\in\tau_Y\}$$

After all we want subsets of $X$, not $Y$ like in your case.

First of all note that both $f$ and $f_1$ (with subspace topology on $f(X)$) generate the same topology on $X$ since elements outside of $f(X)$ don't affect preimages. And so $\tau_X=\{f_1^{-1}(O)\ |\ O\in\tau_{f(X)}\}$, which I leave as an exercise.

---

It is well known ([see here for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190213/the-direct-image-of-the-inverse-image-of-a-surjective-map)) that given a surjective function $g:X\to Y$ we have that $g(g^{-1}(A))=A$ for any subset (open or not) $A\subseteq Y$. In fact these two conditions are equivalent.

So if $U\subseteq X$ is open, then by our definition $U=f_1^{-1}(O)$ for some open subset $O\subseteq f_1(X)$. Since $f_1$ is surjective by definition then

$$f_1(U)=f_1(f_1^{-1}(O))=O$$

and thus $f_1$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

$\tau_X$ is actually defined as $\{f^{-1}[O]: O \in \tau_Y\}$ when $f: X \to (Y, \tau_Y)$ is given. For initial topologies induced by families of such maps (like projections in a product), we get a subbase only, but for the case of one map $f$ we can describe the topology $\tau_X$ in this way.

Now as $$f[f^{-1}[O]] = f[X] \cap O\tag{1}$$

for any $O \subseteq Y$, we have that $f$ is open as a map from $X$ to $f[X]$ (the right hand side is relatively open in $f[X]$ if $O$ is chosen to be open in $Y$ to consider the image of an arbitrary member of $\tau_X$).

To see $(1)$: let $y \in f[f^{-1}[O]]$ so that $y= f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}[O]$, which means $y= f(x) \in O$ and by definition too $y \in f[X]$ so that $y \in f[X] \cap O$. Conversely, if $y \in f[X] \cap O$ we have that $y \in O$ and $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in X$. But as $f(x)=y \in O$ we have that $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ and so $y= f(x) \in f[f^{-1}[O]]$ as required.